# Inheritence and @BeforeSuite in TestNG

Tags: java, inheritance, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have been working on TestNG and there was a problem associated with some of my code. Here's the code:

```
public class Main {
public String baseurl ;
public WebDriver webdriver ;
protected Main(){

    //baseurl = "http://goodreads.com";
    //webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();

}

@BeforeSuite
public void setup(){

    baseurl = "http://goodreads.com";
    webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

Above code is of the base class

```
@Test
public void do_login(){

    super.webdriver.get(super.baseurl);
```

This is of inherited class

Now as far as I know the BeforeSuite should executed first and the values of baseurl and webdriver should get initialized to the specified values. But I'm getting a NullPointerException in the above code. The problem is resolved when I assign the variables as static or if I initialize the variables in the constructor. But why are they not being initialized when I put them in the method(which is supposed to execute before the @Test executes anyway)? Is there some concept about java that I'm missing? Please explain

Comment: They are supposed to execute when you run the tests in a suite and keep that class in the suite, then before starting executing @test methods it will run the before suite method . How are you running the test ?

Comment: I'm using testng.xml file to run the test suite. And I have included both the classes in the file

Comment: Did the solution below solve your problem? It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include both classes to the suite. Only @Test containing class should be included. I think that's the problem. I also believe that @BeforeSuite annotated method will be executed not depending on the way you run your tests (as TestNG method or TestNG suite), since default suite will be created in order to run tests anyway.